# How can I stop building if property does not exist when using filter in Maven

Tags: maven

I'm currently using Maven Filter to configure XML files. The problem is the building won't failed or give any warns even you wrote an error property which doesn't exists in the filter file.
I think it's very dangerous. If one of my colleagues added a property in the XML file and forget to tell us. After building (without any warning or errors), the property in the XML file will be left like ${XX.XX.XX}. That'll surely cause problems when running the system.

**Is there a way to stop the build if Maven finds a property doesn't match anything in the filter file?**

Comment: Almost forgot, I'm using Maven 2.2.1

Comment: Looks like this approach is not possible at present.

Comment: did you report this as an issue to the Maven team? I think it's worth to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think maven-enforcer-plugin should be able to solve your problem. 
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin/